# Angular - Não consigo fazer os arquivos gerados pelo build (npm) funcionarem no localhost

Tags: angular

Executei o comando build (opção dev) e copiei a pasta dist dentro da pasta htdocs do XAMPP. Ao chamar o projeto no browser, o app-root não é reconhecido e não mostra nada na página index.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Forms</title>
  <!--
  <base href="/">
  -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636683/9555410

Tente isso

Comment: Executando o build dessa forma funcionou corretamente.
Muito obrigado jraspante.